# CStatusBar::SetIndicators is returing a value of 0

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, statusbar

As far as I am aware this actually works, so it might be a red herring. But ...

I have this definition:

```
static UINT BASED_CODE indicators[] =
{
    ID_INDICATOR_DATE,
    ID_INDICATOR_ZOOM,
    ID_INDICATOR_CALENDARS,
    ID_INDICATOR_MEETING_TYPE
};
```

Note that the value of `ID_INDICATOR_DATE` is `33604`.

---

At the appropriate  moment during my dialog's create I set the indicators for my status bar:

```
m_StatusBar.SetIndicators(&indicators[0], to_underlying(StatusBarPane::Count)); //Set the number of panes
```

I noticed in debug mode:

> 12d:\a01_work\20\s\src\vctools\VC7Libs\Ship\ATLMFC\Src\MFC\barstat.cpp(128) : AppMsg - Warning: failed to load indicator string `0x8344`.

I determined that `0x8344` is hexadecimal for `33604`.

---

I realised that [`SetIndicators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstatusbar-class?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(AFXEXT%252FCStatusBar%253A%253ASetIndicators)%3Bk(CStatusBar%253A%253ASetIndicators)%3Bk(SetIndicators)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-160#setindicators) returns a `BOOL` so I tested the result and it was `0`. Since the official documentation does not say how to proceed from here - what to do? My panes appear to be operational.

The indicators array is defined at the top of the CPP file. And the statusbar is created in `OnInitDialog`.

Comment: It may sound elementary, but is a `ID_INDICATOR_DATE` string defined in a string-table in your resource script? It must be defined, and contain an string of length at least equal to the max your pane may display, because the framework uses this to determine the pane's width (pls take into account that the font would rather be variable-pitch - if it will be showing only numbers it's easier because for most fonts numbers are fixed-pitch actually).

Comment: Also, the 1st element of the indicators array must typically be `ID_SEPARATOR`, as a variable-length pseudo-element (it won't be showing anything actually) to make the rest right-aligned.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou It turns out that none of these constants are in the `STRINGTABLE`. I actually set the widtsh myself, for example: `_StatusBar.SetPaneInfo(to_underlying(StatusBarPane::Date), ID_INDICATOR_DATE, SBPS_NORMAL, 200);`.

Comment: So the warning should be resolved when you add `STRINGTABLE` for those constants to .rc file